# What should be here instead of "???" PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

It's giving me errors because of the question marks so I was wondering what should I replace them with?I'm quite new to this so sorry if I phrased it badly.

```
create unique index product_meta_table_productid_uindex
      on product_meta_table using ??? ("productId");
```

If there is anything else you guys need I will be very happy to do so, thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`using ...` defines an [index type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html).

It is optional and when left out, will create a B-Tree index which is a sensible choice for a unique index on a string or number column.

So

```
create unique index product_meta_table_productid_uindex
      on product_meta_table ("productId");
```

is the same as

```
create unique index product_meta_table_productid_uindex
      on product_meta_table using btree ("productId");
```